# Why can I only change write permissions for all users?

Tags: permissions

I've been trying to manage the permissions on a certain file, but the only changes the chmod command seems to allow me are changes to all users and regarding the write command. I can't change any permission on a specific permission group, and on all three the only permission I can edit is the write permission. I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: You've provided few specific details.  What OS/release are you using, what type of file-system is involved, and how was it mounted?  Some file-systems cannot store all detail/permissions & they are set at mount, and you gave no clues as to where on the file-system it is (*as if it's within a squashfs for example as it intentionally RO*).  Providing a copy/paste of your command with results (including $PWD or present directory) would be helpful in helping you.

Comment: Read `man chmod chown stat`.

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.